# How to get fat16 or fat32 or ntfs filesystem on Linux

Tags: java, filesystems, ntfs, fat32, fat

I tried this code:

```
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("df -T");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] values = line.split(" ");
            for (String str : values) {
                System.out.println(str);
                if (str.equals("NTFS")){
                    System.out.println("NTFS");
                }
            }
            //System.out.println(line);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but isn write the ntfs , how can i do to work fine? or i have to use other command?
I just want to check which filesystem use.
df -T:

```
  Filesystem                       1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
  /dev/mapper/centos_vjanurik-root  52403200 42261280  10141920  81% /
  devtmpfs                           3894660        0   3894660   0% /dev
  tmpfs                              3904524     4892   3899632   1% /dev/shm
  tmpfs                              3904524     9168   3895356   1% /run
  tmpfs                              3904524        0   3904524   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
  /dev/mapper/centos_vjanurik-home  56235184 29428876  26806308  53% /home
  /dev/sda1                           508588   107384    401204  22% /boot
```

Comment: What you want to achieve?

Comment: **Why** do you want to do this? What is the result of `df -T` on the command line? What output do you expect? What output do you get?

Answer (score 1):

On my system `df -T` outputs the file system type in lowercase.  You are comparing against `"NTFS"` .... uppercase.

Also, the output you have shown us doesn't appear to be output from regular Linux `df -T` ... because it doesn't have the `Type` column.